# Installing 3rd party packages in Laravel 5.2

Tags: service, laravel-5

I am trying to install Laravel Datatables.

Ok with composer and I can see the files under vendor, but the next part of the instruction is to add this to a service provider

```
yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider
```

Where?

I've got the bit about the route of the facade but where do I tell it about the service provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to open your `app.php` file located under `config/app.php` there you will find `provider` Array, add your this line `yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider` into `provider` array

Comment: I have tagged yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::cLass, on to the list of Application Service Providers... Is this correct?